# IOS app rejection 2. 1 PERFORMANCE: APP COMPLETENESS

Tags: ios, app-store, ipv6, cloudkit, error-reporting

I need help debugging this crash report, i'm guessing the crash is on thread 0, line 22 main (__hidden#771_:18).
  This don't show me whats causing the crash though.
  This only happens when testing using iCloud production and works fine using iCloud development mode.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1904891b8 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18eec055c objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x190489100 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
3   UIKit                           0x196593860 -[UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 240
4   Stream It                       0x10010bad8 _hidden#209_ (__hidden#771_:368)
5   Stream It                       0x10010dfac _hidden#228_ (__hidden#771_:0)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x18f3121fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x18f3121bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x18f316d68 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
9   CoreFoundation                  0x190436810 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
10  CoreFoundation                  0x1904343fc __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
11  CoreFoundation                  0x1903622b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
12  GraphicsServices                0x191e16198 GSEventRunModal + 180
13  UIKit                           0x1963a97fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
14  UIKit                           0x1963a4534 UIApplicationMain + 208
15  Stream It                       0x10010842c main (__hidden#771_:18)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x18f3455b8 start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f457014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f51f450 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018f3cb400 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018ee952d4 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018eeb2cc0 default_unexpected_handler() + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018eec0844 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018eeaf66c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018eeaef84 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018eec0690 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 0
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190489100 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
10  UIKit                           0x0000000196593860 -[UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 240
11  Stream It                       0x000000010010bad8 _hidden#209_ (__hidden#771_:0)
12  Stream It                       0x000000010010dfac _hidden#228_ (__hidden#771_:0)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f3121fc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f3121bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f316d68 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000190436810 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001904343fc __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001903622b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
19  GraphicsServices                0x0000000191e16198 GSEventRunModal + 180
20  UIKit                           0x00000001963a97fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
21  UIKit                           0x00000001963a4534 UIApplicationMain + 208
22  Stream It                       0x000000010010842c main (__hidden#771_:18)
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018f3455b8 start + 4
```

Comment: You're reading it a bit upside-down.  :)  The error happens when something in your code calls `scrollToItem`.  (That's where the NSException originates.)  The exception codes suggest that -- maybe -- you're passing zero or an empty value when you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments, it pointed me in the right direction.
 The problem was, I was using a search on my records and whilst i ticked the boxes for search in development mode I never deployed this into production mode.
 A real simple error that took me ages to find, hence when Phillip Mills mentioned the scroll to index, i twigged on.
 Thank you for your help, and also it had nothing to do with ipv6 connection thanks Apple, haha.